# What's the correct syntax to check the income viewbag in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

i have an action in the controller that returns 3 viewbags.
is it possible to check in razor which Viewbag the controller has sent. ?

here my controller

```
     public ActionResult Details(string Query, long Id)
      {
    // some code......
        switch (Query)
        {

            case ("Operationer"):
                ViewBag.Query =Operationer;
               break;

            case ("Material"):
                ViewBag.Query = Material;
                break;

           Case("items"):
                 Viewbag.Query= items;
                   break;
        }

         return view();
          }
```

and here in my razor view

```
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LayoutDetails.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

 @ if ( the incom Viewbag == "material")
   {  
 Create table for material 
   }
  @ else if ( the income Viewbaf == "items")
  { 
 create table for items
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

C#

```
public ActionResult Details(string Query, long Id)
  {
// some code......
    switch (Query)
    {

        case ("Operationer"):
            ViewBag.Query ="Operationer";
           break;

        case ("Material"):
            ViewBag.Query = "Material";
            break;

       Case("items"):
             Viewbag.Query= "items";
               break;
    }

     return view();
      }
```

VIEW

```
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Details";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LayoutDetails.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>Details</h2>

 @ if (ViewBag.Query == "Material")
  {  
     Create table for material 
  }
else if ( ViewBag.Query == "items")
{ 
  create table for items
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, Because ViewBag is cartying a List of items, so it givs wrong when i try to check if it = String

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to Viewbag to denote the type:

```
Viewbag.QueryName = Query;
```

Then in view:

```
@if(Viewbag.QueryName  == "materials)
{  // etc....
}
```

...so, why are you doing all this with Viewbag, instead of a view-model?